# Android Record audio from Bluetooth A2DP source

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp, sink

I have a custom bluetooth wearable that essentially has two microphones, streams A2DP and handles AVRCP commands.  I would like to connect this device to an Android phone and record audio either with AudioRecord or in native code.  I need to do some signal processing on the data so I can't have it record directly to a file.

I have managed to build a version of Android using AOSP which will pair with the device and appears to receive the A2DP stream but I have not been able to build a version of the OS/SDK that allows me to use AudioRecord.  I have gotten to the point where I can add a source for A2DP but I'm missing something at the native layer to fully make the connection.

Ideally, I would also like to control the input with AVRCP.

I am currently testing with a hammerhead device, but am will to move to another device if that works better.

Any input appreciated.